# Excel Spreadsheet Not Sorting

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, sorting

In my excel spreadsheet, I am trying to randomly sort a large list. I am doing this by adding in a new column to my table. This table is assigned a random integer between 1 and 10. This is done by =FLOOR(10 * RAND(), 1). Then I want to sort this list of numbers from smallest to largest.

All of this is working except the sorting. When I try to sort it, excel changes the order of the numbers slightly, but it is not from smallest to largest.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: The rand() function recalculates itself. You need to copy and paste values, then sort.

Comment: If you're getting your data sorted based on the first set of random numbers, isn't that good enough?  Do you need to maintain a record of the random values that were the basis for the sort?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your rows are sorted by the previous values of `=RAND()`.

After sorting, the `=RAND()` function is called again.

Turn off Automatic Calculation from Formulas (ribbon), Calculation Options, Manual.