# How can I randomize data in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

So my data is all in order now, least to greatest, but I want it in NOT order.

How can I randomize my data in 2010?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel Spreadsheet Not Sorting](http://superuser.com/questions/925805/excel-spreadsheet-not-sorting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have your data

[image: data1]

Then, you have =RAND() in the B column

[image: rand in b]

Fill in the rest.

[image: rand-fill]

Special sort, in which you sort by the B column

[image: randomize]

And randomized data.

[image: ta-da]

Comment: `copy - paste values` otherwise rand() will constantly recalc